# Pandas dataframe: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, valueerror

I have a matrix like this and I want the diagonal to be 1 if the row sums to 0. In this case, (2,2) and (3,3) will become 1. I wrote a for loop. Though using .all(), it is giving me a value error point to the if line.

```
Markov_sub

           1      2   3        4           5           6
1   0.997476    0.0 0.0 0.002414    0.000110    0.000000
2   0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
3   0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
4   0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.997281    0.002521    0.000173
5   0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.000693    0.999222    0.000054
6   0.000046    0.0 0.0 0.035641    0.964293    0.000000

for i in (range(0, len(Markov_sub.index)-1)):
    if 0 == Markov_sub.iloc[[i]].all():
        Markov_sub.iloc[i, i] = 1
Markov_sub
```

Comment: `Markov_sub.iloc[[i]]` returns a single row DataFrame and the default axis of `.all()` is to operate over each column so you still get a  Boolean Series as the result. You either need `Markov_sub.iloc[[i]].all(axis=1)` or really just slice the row as a Series to begin with: `Markov_sub.iloc[i].all()`

Comment: Didn't you mention `if the row sums to 0`? Shouldn't it be `df.sum(axis=1).eq(0)` instead?

Comment: Hi @ALollz, thanks for the input! And just want to print out the line for future reference:)  if (0 == test.iloc[i]).all(): ------that there are parentheses aroung 0 == iloc.